# The angle to shoot moving object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I am obliged to count very simple problem (at least it seemed that it is simple, I hope it isn't to simple for this site). So i got observer who is standing $H$ below the object. The object is fired horizontaly with the speed $V_{0}$. Assuming that the observer has the reaction time that equals $T$, on what angle he should fire his bullet to destroy the object. We also know that bullet is fired with the speed $V_{1}$.

So I drew picture (I changed the orientation because the computation seems simplier):
[image]

And I write equations for bullet:

$x(t)=V_{1}\cos(\alpha)\cdot t$

$y(t)=V_1\sin(\alpha)\cdot t + H - \frac{gt^2}{2}$

And for object:

$x_{1}(t)=V_{0}(t+T)$

$y_{2}(t)=\frac{g(t+T)^2}{2}$

Now I do $x(t)=x_{1}(t)$ :

and i get:
$\cos (\alpha)=\frac{V_0\cdot(t+T)}{V_{1}t}$

From the second equation $y_{1}(x)=y(x)$
I count $t$ (the time they will meet) and move it to the equation $\cos (\alpha)=\frac{V_0\cdot(t+T)}{V_{1}t}$.
I got very complicated and hard equations that I am not able to solve, so I am asking is it simplier way to this kind of task? Or did I miss something that makes me equations very complicated?

Comment: If the computation seems simplier and is still "very complicated and hard" then I'm afraid what would it be without the change :)

Comment: @Wojciech Before, the computetions were very very hard, now they are very complicated :) I mean it is almost impossible the find the value for me. I mean I am not bad at maths but still it is impossible for me to solve :( I tried multiple ways, to solve this. It does not let me rest, there must be easier way to do this because Physics at my studies is not very hard, it usually comes to solving simple problems. Don't you have any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe I have bad approach? I should start differently?

Comment: Minor correction: you should have $y_{2}(t)=-\frac{g(t+T)^2}{2}$, not $y_{2}(t)=\frac{g(t+T)^2}{2}$.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Why? I changed the orientation so the object should fall in the same direction as gravity works.

Comment: @MarcinMajewski: Whoops, actually I meant to say it should be $y(t)=V_1\sin(\alpha)\cdot t + H + \frac{gt^2}{2}$, not $y(t)=V_1\sin(\alpha)\cdot t + H - \frac{gt^2}{2}$, so that gravity affects both the object and bullet in the same direction.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Yeah, you right, thank you. But still the solution is unknown.

Comment: The best I can come up with is that the angle is the zero of an extremely long function which is too long to post in a comment. There might be a simple closed-form expression for the zero, but the approach I tried in Mathematica created a solution which was about 30 pages long, so it probably won't be easy to find. I can post it if you like.

Comment: Equations seem to be allright, but I'm too tired to try to solve them. I'll try something tomorrow, if nobody suceeds.